# Compiler error: Expected identifier or (

Tags: objective-c

I have the following struct in a C header file.

```
typedef struct GSPathInfo {
        unsigned char pathIndex;        // 0x0 = 0x5C
        unsigned char pathIdentity;     // 0x1 = 0x5D
        unsigned char pathProximity;    // 0x2 = 0x5E
        CGFloat pathPressure;               // 0x4 = 0x60
        CGFloat pathMajorRadius;        // 0x8 = 0x64
        CGPoint pathLocation;           // 0xC = 0x68
        GSWindowRef pathWindow;         // 0x14 = 0x70
    } GSPathInfo;   // sizeof = 0x18.
```

In the objective C (.mm)file I am doing the following:

```
-(void)GettingFingerSizeInfo {
    CGFloat pressure =  GSPathInfo.pathPressure 
}
```

The Xcode complain: Expected identifier or (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have not created anywhere to hold the information for a GSPathInfo structure and to set values in its fields. You need a variable to hold the structure.

e.g.

```
GSPathInfo pathinfo = malloc(sizeof(GSPathInfo));
pathinfo.pathPressure = 1.0f;

...

CGFloat pressure =  pathinfo.pathPressure;
```

Also note that.mm files are for Objective C++, .m are for Objective C

Comment: upvoting this as it's a better answer.  nice catch Mark.

Answer (score 1):

are you including the .h file at the top of your .mm file?

and more importantly, put a semicolon *after*  pathPressure in that function.

e.g.

```
-(void)GettingFingerSizeInfo {
    CGFloat pressure =  GSPathInfo.pathPressure;
}
```

lastly, just a suggestion... best (or standard) practice in Objective C is to start method names with a lower case letter.  So instead of "`GettingFingerSizeInfo`", declare it as "`gettingFingerSizeInfo`".